# Abraham Twitter OAuth Library Special Characters Problem

Tags: php, twitter, character-encoding, oauth

I'm using [Abraham's Twitter OAuth Library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) to post status updates on twitter.

It works well but there is a problem with character set, I guess.
There are characters in my language which are not english such as `ö` `ü` `ç`.
When I use these characters, it won't post my status update, is there any work around ?
I don't want to convert non-english characters to english characters.
I want to use characters in my own language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you try to put in the way of html entites like http://www.texaswebdevelopers.com/examples/xmlentities/xml_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check which character encoding the status updates must be encoded in with twitter. Then change the encoding which you have into the encoding that twitter has.

I guess it's [perecent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.6) but can not say specifically.

Send the updates then in twitter's encoding and you should get the expected result.